# Designing a basic Restful API in PHP

Tags: php, rest, restful-architecture

This is a Homework task. It involves creating a simple DB and making CURL calls to the server to get results from the DB, accordingly I have a DBClass file with the required methods. I understand what REST architecture is in general, but I am kind of unable to put the pieces together. Here's what I have so far:

1. `Model.class.php` ->  this is the Database class that instantiates connections to the DB and has methods that execute DB queries and return the result.
2. `Simulator.php` -> helper class, simulates HTTP requests (POST or GET only) to the localhost so my curl call is made to 'http://localhost/app/index.php'
3. `index.php` -> here is where I receive the CURL requests, in effect, I decode the HTTP requests to understand the request method, parameters, URI as such.

At this point, I am lost. Understandably a RESTful API request essentially is of the kind server/getMeMyBananas and getMeMyBananas is a DB method that looks for bananas for the user and returns the ID's. I am confused how this maps into the index.php file and the missing pieces.

Suggestions and links to awesome resources are most welcome. I am not interested in security or creating a state of the art Web service.

Comment: You could simulate the rest with mod_rewrite like wordpress does for example. so index.php?m=getmebananas becomes http:/localhost/getmebananas/

Comment: here's a link to a tutorial on mod_rewrite http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/

Answer (score 1):

getMeMyBananas is an example of an RPC route

In REST, the four main HTTP verbs GET, POST, PUT and DELETE are the verbs to act upon a noun (a resource).

REST is not a standard. It's a loose recommendation on how to form an API for a remote system using HTTP as its foundation.

There's nothing to say that you can't design RPC-like routes in a REST API. People do it all of the time. It's just that you mainly use the verbs to create (POST), retrieve (GET), update (PUT) or delete (DELETE). That makes the acronym CRUD. So, with REST, you are able to cover a lot of scenarios in information exchange simply by sticking to CRUD.

So, you can start by designing your URLs (routes) to resemble nouns (resources) and build a switch case in PHP to switch on the HTTP verb. Keep in mind, there's nothing stopping from and there's nothing wrong with having RPC-like routes. In fact, you can't handle all cases with the simple REST CRUD scenario, so you'll have to handle cases that don't fit into that scenario with RPC-like routes.

See:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/rest.html

Later, if you are interested in a built out API in PHP, I built an API infrastructure and open sourced it. I'm not sure if it'll help you, but here it is:

https://github.com/homer6/blank_altumo

Comment: Good Points, so GET localhost/bananas to retrieve a list, POST localhost/bananas to create a new one etc.

Comment: Yes, you can think of POST as posting a letter into a mailbox. Like a datagram, you don't know it's ID or what happened to is once it leaves visibility. PUT, however, is for when you do know the ID, which is why it's commonly used to modify an existing record. The only reason that POST is associated with creation is because you typically don't assign the ID in a database-backed API (which includes most of them). The database would assign it based on the auto increment. However, if you knew the ID (say, it was a name instead of a autoincrementing integer), you could use PUT to create the record

Comment: If you stick to the POST as create and PUT as edit, you're not likely to get harassed about it anywhere. Most people understand it at that level.

Comment: can you elaborate on which part you need further clarification on?

Answer (score 1):

You can map any url to any path you want! 
For example, when using Apache you can use [ModRewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to turn `http://ex.com/rest/bananas` into `http://ex.com/index.php?p1=rest&p2=bananas`

From there you can now you can fetch your request parameters with the global variable get for example: `$_GET["p1"]`.
I would suggest you to perform [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) test on those.
After that when you've got the data, I'd suggest to package it in JSON so almost any client can read it.

That's basically how I'd do it! If you've got more questions go ahead :)

Comment: thanks @marctrem. So technically there could be several methods such as getBananas, getApples, saveApples, saveBananas etc, each of which have corresponding methods in my DB.class.php file. And my index.php file initializes an instance of the DB class that accordingly gets/posts these resources.

Comment: to do this, there are corresponding methods in index.php such as getBananas(){return $this->DBObject->getBananas();}. What I am not able to wrap my head around is the ModRewrite. I get you can map any URL to any path, but getBananas() is a method in my index.php file, it isn't a path. This is where I am getting confused :(

Comment: spawn your object in a switch statement. I pretty much like switch statements because they prevent XSS on server includes you can do

    switch($_GET["p2"])
    {
        case "getBananas":
            //spawn getBananas
        break;
        case "getWhatever":
            //spawn getWhatever
        break;
        case default:
            //spawn error, did not understand
        break;
}